# What should be included in the Multimedia Attachment of a Journal Submission?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I have recently completed a paper on Humanoid Robot, and I am willing to submit it to the Robotics and Automation Letters(RA-L) journal. What should be submitted as part of the Multimedia attachment?
Are result videos sufficient? Or Is the code also necessary to be attached?

Also, I have a citation which is not yet available online, can I include a copy of this in this attachment?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the journal?

Comment: No, I haven't contacted the journal. Are attachments specific to different jounals?

Comment: They can be different, yes. Your question is quite specific, with a particular journal in mind, so it would make most sense to ask that journal. An alternative would be to make your question more general and ask what is common practice in your field. That might provide you with the experience of others. At the end of the day, however, the advice would still probably be to contact the journal or at least check their submissions guidelines on their website.